# deleting a particular line from .txt file in cshell

Tags: linux, bash

I have several .txt files named `submit.txt` with a line

```
bsub -q l ./dolist.csh
```

i want to delete this line from all those file what i am doing now is following but it it gives me following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown command: `m'
```

code used is:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                            

for(( x=7; x<=65 ; x+=2))
do
    cd arm_$x
    sed -i '/bsub -q l ./dolist.csh/d' submit.txt
    cd ../
done
```

please tell me what is going wrong here

Comment: Notice that you are using forward slashes as delimiters, but you also have one in the string itself. Precede with a backslash, or surround in `[]`.

Comment: Looks like you neee to escape the forward slash in your argument. sed treats it like a delimiter for its commad.

Comment: thanks, adding a backlash before forward slash works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pattern of a `/.../` command contains a `/`,
it breaks the syntax.
One solution is to escape embedded `/` with `\`:

```
sed -i '/bsub -q l \.\/dolist\.csh/d' submit.txt
```

Another alternative is to use a different delimiter for the `/.../` command.
The syntax for that is `\?...?` where `?` can be any character (but typically `?` is used), for example:

```
sed -i '\?bsub -q l \./dolist\.csh?d' submit.txt
```

This syntax is very useful when you have multiple embedded `/` and escaping all of them would not be practical or the command would become hard to read.

Notice that in both examples I also escaped all the `.` characters,
because they have the special meaning in regular expressions to match any character, not just a dot.
If you don't escape the `.`, lines like `bsub -q l x/dolistycsh` would also match, incorrectly.
Although you probably don't expect such lines in the file,
it's good to be accurate.